# How to use a transition matte with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have four videos in mp4 format, I am using the following command to concat the videos into one video:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -i 3.mp4 -i 4.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v] [1:v] [2:v] [3:v] concat=n=4:v=1 [v]" -map "[v]"  nibblez2.mp4
```

I have a file called transition1.mp4 which I want to use as a transition matte between the 4 files.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all inputs have the same attributes:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -i 3.mp4 -i 4.mp4 -i transition1.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v] [4:v] [1:v] [4:v] [2:v] [4:v] [3:v] concat=n=7:v=1:a=0 [v]" -map "[v]" nibblez2.mp4
```

Comment: Get's stuck and there is no response for a long time.

Comment: @AminBaig Edit your question and show the command and the complete log.